# Error saving custom model Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-form-recognizer

Can anyone help with the tutorial for the training of a custom form model?

I'm basically just trying to follow [the tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-sample-label-tool#train-a-custom-form-model):

Everything goes well until point 8 when I try to save my project.

I see the error message:

> Form Recognizer Error: Check if you have unexpired
> read/write/list/delete permission to blob container/blob.

[image]

This is how I've configured the SAS for my blob container:
[image]

And this is how I've configured the connection:
[image]

CORS has been enabled in the storage account:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you include create permissions with your sas token? The training process will need to create a few files in the container.

Just looked at the CORS image again and realized you have enabled CORS for the Studio not the labeling tool. Your screenshot #1 (dark background) is the FOTT labeling tool not the studio.

Edit your CORS setting to whitelist https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/ or the URL from the address bar of your labeling tool.

Comment: You could also try using the Form Recognizer Studio where this step is handled for you. https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/studio

Comment: Thanks @Vinod but I get exactly the same (frustrating) error: Failed to access Blob container
Check existence and CORS configuration of selected Blob container.
To enable cross-domain resource sharing on Azure storage account for data accessing, follow the configuration instruction